# Java check if something was added to a string

Tags: java, string, return

I periodically check if a string which I get from a web service changed. This works just fine but if an old string is deleted from my method triggers, too.
For Example:

```
//I get this at the beginning
"One,Two,Three"

//And at the next check I get this
"Two,Three"
```

So the String changed and my method returned true like it is supposed to do.
But I only want to return true if e.g. "Four" is added to the string.

Can anyone give me a solution for this problem?

Thank you a lot,

Freezed

Comment: Can't understand your problem. Can you be more clear, please?

Comment: I get the String

    "One, Two, Three"

and I want to return true if I add something to that string but not when I remove something.
So:

    "One, Two, Three, Four" //This would return true
    "Two, Three, Four" //This would return true too
    "Four, Five, Six" //This would return true too
    "Two, Three" //This should return false

Comment: Java `String` is immutable, exactly **how** is something being added to it? You could test if the reference changes... `a != b` (which is normally not how one would compare `String` instances). Or even `a.hashCode() != b.hashCode()` - which is *probably* good enough.

Comment: Well it's not "added". It's basically a new String which can have less, the same or more information than the privious string.

Comment: @FreezedHD it seems you have a pattern here. You always have three values, separate by comma. So you can split your string and check if its length is less than 3. If less, return false.

Comment: This was just an example. There could be a million values ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `split` like so

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String oldString = "This,Is,A,Test";
        String[] oldItems = oldString.split(",");

        String newString = "This,Is,A,New";
        String[] newItems = newString.split(",");

        // For each new item, check all old items
        for (String newItem: newItems)
        {
            Boolean foundItem = false;
            for (String oldItem: oldItems)
            {
                // Item was already in the old items
                if (newItem.equals(oldItem))
                {
                    foundItem = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // New item is not in the old list of items
            if (!foundItem)
            {
                System.out.println("New item added: " + newItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never thought of the idea to use a for loop to compare the two strings. Great idea. I will try this out!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!oldstring.contains(newstring)))  
return true;
```

Comment: But the new string doesn't have to be longer than the old string

Comment: @FreezedHD  this should be good, or you have more test cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
newString.contains(oldString) && !newString.equals(oldString)
```

Comment: This won't work. `"Two,Three"` will not contain `"One,Two,Three"`

Comment: The problem with you idea is that the new string doesnt have to contain the old string. I could get something like "Four, Five, Six" :/

Comment: unfortunately not. Reason for this is because I just want to return true if something was added. This solution would also return true if I remove something from the string :/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just trigger when the length of the string increases? The question doesn't state that what is being added matters--only whether something is being added at all.

```
boolean result = false;

if(newString.length() > oldString.length()) {
    result = true;
    break;
}

return result;
```

EDIT: Based on further clarification, I understand that the length of the string is not the best indicator, since something can be removed and added at the same time, in which case OP wants `true` returned--even if length is shorter. Here's a solution that splits the strings into tokens, and then checks whether the last token of the old string occurs before the last token of the new string, because that means something was added after it:

```
boolean result = false;
String delim = ",";
String oldStringTokens[] = oldString.split(delim);
String newStringTokens[] = newString.split(delim);

for(int i = 0; i < newStringTokens.length; i++) {
    if(oldStringTokens[oldStringTokens.length-1].equals(newStringTokens[i])) {
        if(i < newStringTokens.length - 1) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
}

return result;
```

Comment: but i dont want to return true if something was removed from the string

Comment: Your updated answer won't work in the case that an item was added elsewhere other than the last item. View my answer instead.

Comment: In several clarifications, OP did not indicate that data may be added anywhere other than the end of the string.

Comment: This provides the smaller amount of overhead, but of course would not work if data are being added elsewhere.

Comment: OP clarified in a comment on their original post. But yes, this would work in the case that all new items are added to the end of the string.